# JavaFX's Media Player not retrieving metadata

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I'm creating a video player using JavaFX media player library. I need to retrieve the metadata and display in a window. I'm having problems retrieving the data though.

I've read 2 threads about this already and I understand that this is done asynchronously so I need a listener in order to get the metadata.

First Thread:[Retrieving metadata from media files in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186951/retrieving-metadata-from-media-files-in-javafx)
Second Thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43144197/12787326

This code has been implemented like so below.

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

   //Initialising path of the media file, replace this with your file path
    String path = "Video.mp4";

    //Instantiating Media class
    Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());

    //Listener
    media.getMetadata().addListener((MapChangeListener<String,Object>) change-> {
      System.out.println(change);
    });

   //Instantiating MediaPlayer class
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mv.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);


    mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> {

    ...

      mediaPlayer.play();
    });


  }
```

I have tried a variety of different changes to the listener such as placing it in different areas of the code and trying to get the data from the mediaPlayer, which accesses the media itself. None of these seems to have fixed the problem.

I've tried print statements in the code trying to print off the contents of `media.getMetadata` but all I get is an empty list back.

I've tried creating a listener for `media.getTracks()` and that works as expected with updating each time the player switches its status. So that makes me wonder what is going wrong with `media.getMetadata()`

[This is what the metadata of the video currently looks like so I assume I should be getting this infomarmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikZn6.png)

I think the listener isn't seeing anything change, that's why `print(change)` is never reached. However, even if that is true, shouldn't me doing a `system.out.print(media.getMetaData())` in the  `setOnAction` code give me the data? Because when I try that all I get is an empty list.

Does anyone know how to fix this or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the MP4 file has any of the [supported metadata tags](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html)? If it does, where in the file is the metadata stored?